# Create a function that auto detects the color format, rgb or hex, and converts it to hex or rgb respectively

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

The question is:
Write a function that converts HEX to RGB. Then Make that function auto-dect the formats so that if you enter HEX color format it returns RGB and if you enter RGB color format it returns HEX.

I wrote this:

```
//Function to convert hex to rgb
const hexTorgb = (hex) => {
    const r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
    const g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
    const b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);
    
    // return {r, g, b} 
    return { r, g, b };
}

console.log(hexTorgb("#ff33ff"));
/*
{
  "r": 255,
  "g": 51,
  "b": 255
}
*/
//Functions to convert rgb to hex
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {

  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
```

But, I am missing something in the function to auto-detecte the format. Right now, I got this, but I'm getting an error when I try to use this next function to detect the format

```
function detect(input) {
    if (input.includes('#')) {
        return console.log(hexTorgb(input))
    } else if (input.includes(',')){
        console.log(rgbToHex(input))
    }
}
```

When I wrote in RGB format, I get an error

```
detect(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: "I'm always getting an error" - please edit your question to include the exact error and the input that triggered it.

Comment: your function `function rgbToHex(r, g, b)` need 3 arguments, and you giv it only one here : `rgbToHex(input)`

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you so much, i will try to solve that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's good, but I thought it was more a question of doing a more "literal" conversion, using standard textual syntax, like in CSS.

```js
const
  x2n     = x    => parseInt(x,16) // convert hexa value to number
, n2x     = n    => `0${n.toString(16)}`.slice(-2).toUpperCase() // convert n to 2digits Hexa
, rgb2hex = rgb  => rgb.match(/\d+/g).reduce((s,x)=>s+n2x(Number(x)),'#')
, hex2rgb = hexa => 'rgb('+hexa.match(/([\da-f]{2})/gi).map(x2n).join(',')+')'
  ;

function reverse_RGB_Hexa(input)  // need to be improved by a regex control
  {
  if      (input.includes('#')) return hex2rgb(input);
  else if (input.includes(',')) return rgb2hex(input);
  else                          return 'unknown input value';
  }
  
console.log( reverse_RGB_Hexa("#1A0BFF"));         // rgb(26,11,255)
console.log( reverse_RGB_Hexa('rgb(26,11,255)'));  // #1A0BFF
console.log( reverse_RGB_Hexa('fdgkjl') )          // unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

After correcting from one input to three inputs, I still had to make some adjustments like setting variables to r, g, b e hex, to assume the value of the inputs

```js
//Function to convert hex to rgb
const hexTorgb = (hex) => {
    const r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
    const g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
    const b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);
    
    // return {r, g, b} 
    return { r, g, b };
}

//Functions to convert rgb to hex
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {

  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}


function convert(input1, input2, input3) {
    if (input2===undefined) {
        var hex = input1
        console.log(hexTorgb(hex))
    } else {
        var r = input1
        var g = input2
        var b = input3
        console.log(rgbToHex(r,g,b))
    }}

convert('#ff33ff')
convert('0','0','0')
```